# Minecraft Forge profile won't launch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

Sorry if this is a repost but I am getting very frustrated by trying to install the Minecraft aether 2 mod. 
I am on a mac, the launcher is version 1.4.4 and I think the most updated version is minecraft 1.7.10. I am following this youtube tutorial:

I downloaded the forge and I got the Forge profile, but when I click play the bar fills quickly but nothign happens. I clicked 'development console' and this is what it says (pastebin link because the text is too long): http://pastebin.com/nNkPp3jT
Is there something I am doing wrong, did not install, or did not install correctly? Or is this a system limitation that can't be fixed.

Thank you very much, again I am sorry if this has already been asked.

Comment: Oh also my problem corresponds to 1:16 in the video.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't offer support for modded Minecraft.

Answer (score 3):

This is relatively common, here is what's interesting in the console output:

> [20:59:09 WARN]: Couldn't download http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.2/scala-compiler-2.10.2.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'

You'll see a bunch of threads trying to get various things leading up to that. There's several causes:

- You're not connected to the Internet, or you're on a very high-latency connection which causes the download workers to give up prematurely
- The server (remote) is experiencing difficulty and is down
- The remote resource moved, *or* went to a different version dependency

What's aggravating is there's no status code (404/500/etc) that could give more of a clue. The best thing to do when this happens is try another Internet connection (or location if you can), if that fails, just wait and try again when the remote server is sorted.

This goes for pretty much anything, including mods themselves, that pull in additional resources when they run. To troubleshoot, try accessing the URIs it was trying to grab directly with your browser, and you might discover enough about the issue to report it to the server admins. I checked, and it is a 404 (it's not there, so they probably moved it and the new location wasn't updated in the client code).

Comment: I'm pretty confident my internet connection was fine, but when I tried to paste that URL into the web browser it gave a 404 error. Also, what is a server that you're talking abotu?

Comment: Also it's on a big desktop computer and it's at home so there is only 1 wifi available and I can't physically move the computer...

Comment: @FarazMasroor The launcher has a list of files it needs to download initially in order to meet dependencies, which it's programmed to download from minecraftforge.net. However, the administrators of that server have either moved, or removed the file (probably moved as they switched to a new version of it). Make sure you're using the latest _stable_ version of Forge, and that you've got the latest version of the mod. It _looks_ like this is coming from Forge, not the mod.

Answer (score 1):

One reason could be that you are following a 1.6.2 tutorial. Forge has greatly changed due to 1.7. The 404s in your console show that it is a problem with the files. I checked the URL for one of the files and it was a 404. So you should try updating forge. The files were probably moved. Whats annoying is that Forge did not put in a 301, and instead just let the 404 happen :/

Its not a problem with the Aether, its with Forge. Reinstall it to your current version, not the 1.6 version.

Comment: Will I have to remove any files that I've already downloaded, or can I just repeat what i've done with a different forge?

Comment: @FarazMasroor You don't have to remove the files. It will install a new version of of forge in a new profile, if you are using the manual installer.